# Hash trick in sklearn FeatureHasher

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

Wanting to understand "the hashing trick" I've written the following test code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher
test = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g','h']})
h = FeatureHasher(n_features=4, input_type='string')
f = h.transform(test.type)
print(f.toarray())
```

In the above example, I'm mapping 8 categories into 4 columns, and the output is:

```
[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.]<-a
 [ 0. -1.  0.  0.]<-b
 [ 0. -1.  0.  0.]<-c
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]<-d
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]<-e
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]<-f
 [ 0.  0. -1.  0.]<-g
 [ 0. -1.  0.  0.]]<-g
```

In the resulting matrix, I can see repetitions and some categories are represented the same way. Why is that? 8 categories can be mapped into 4 columns if I use a binary representation.

Can someone please explain the output of this technique and maybe elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`FeatureHasher`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html) will lead to undesired results if you set `n_features` to such a low value. The reason for this is the way in which it maps categories to column indices.

As opposed to a `CountVectorizer` for instance, where each category is assigned a unique integer index corresponding to a column just by order of occurrence, `FeatureHasher` will apply a *hash function* to the features to determine the column index of each category. It's main advantage is hence an *increased speed*. However by limiting `n_features` to such a low value, it is likely that the result of hashing a given category will result in an index *higher* than the set `n_features`, and consequently what you'll get is a *truncated* feature vector.

---

We can actually check this by reproducing how the hashing is done in 
[`_hashing_fast`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/_hashing_fast.pyx) which uses [`murmurhash3_bytes_s32`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/murmurhash.pyx) to generate the hashes:

```
from sklearn.utils.murmurhash import murmurhash3_bytes_s32

raw_X = test['type']
raw_X = iter(raw_X)
raw_X = (((f, 1) for f in x) for x in raw_X)

for x in raw_X:
    for f, v in x:
        f = f'{f}={v}'
        fb = (f).encode("utf-8")
        h = murmurhash3_bytes_s32(fb, seed=0)
        print(f'{f[0]} -> {h}')
```

Which as you can see yields larger hash values precisely for `e` and `f`, which are truncated to the lower hash corresponding to `d`:

```
a -> -424864564
b -> -992685778
c -> -1984769100
d -> 728527081
e -> 2077529484
f -> 2074045163
g -> -1877798433
h -> -51608576
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I thought the whole purpose of FeatureHasher is to generate a lower dimension vector for a high cardinality categories. Also the n_features in the official example (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html) is 10. What am I missing?

Comment: No the default `n_features` is *very* high, precisely `1048576`. I've updated with more details @RoniGadot